# Hand gesture recognition in video stream

Tags: opencv, neural-network, computer-vision

What are the possible ways to recognize hand gesture in a video stream? What I am thinking is to detect and crop hand region and pass it to the neural network or Haar-cascade classifier for gesture recognition(for example: simple finger counting). I'm just curious for alternative solutions and methods. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is really abstract and has many possible answers. Please share an approach that you've tried so as to narrow down your problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways for hand gesture recognition in a video stream. The overall procedure can be generalized as follows.

1. **Detect hand in the first frame of the video** - using Back Projection, Template matching, skin segmentation.
2. **From next frame, Track/Detect the hand** - using Mean-shift or any other tracking algorithm.
3. **Recognize the gesture (Finger count, hand alignment e.t.c.)** - using Convex hull, SVM, Neural Network, Contour analysis e.t.c.

Below are few useful link that you might be interested in.

- [Back Projection based](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html)
- [Color based](http://simena86.github.io/blog/2013/08/12/hand-tracking-and-recognition-with-opencv/)
- [Skin segmentation and convex hull based](https://picoledelimao.github.io/blog/2015/11/15/fingertip-detection-on-opencv/)